# Spurious regression for large T small N logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, panel-data, logit, spurious-correlation

My question is -

Will there be problem of spurious regression for large T small N panel logistic regression (with individual fixed effects),

if the dependent variable is binary (0 or 1), and independent variables are non-stataionary?

T is time dimension, N is individual dimension, and the panel data sample size is N*T

Can nonlinear model (like logit and probit models) have the problem of spurious regression?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: What is T?    BLAH BLAH to make the comment acceptable

Comment: T is time dimension, N is individual dimension, the panel data sample size is N*T

Comment: What do you mean by "spurious regression" in this context? If you just mean that you can find [a marginal association between variables with no direct causal relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship), then of course the answer is *yes*. A non-linear link function is unrelated to whether there is an omitted variable. What are you getting at in noting that the "independent variables are non-stataionary", are you saying that you have [tag:time-varying-covariate]s?